# What is the precedence of recursive invoking of makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

having this makefile:

```
# If KERNELRELEASE is defined, we've been invoked from the
# kernel build system and can use its language.
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
obj-m := module.o
# Otherwise we were called directly from the command
# line; invoke the kernel build system.
else
KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
$(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
endif
```

I have just one question. This makefile is read 2 times. In the first time, it sets the `$KERNELDIR` and `PWD` - the `else` branch. On the second read - there comes me question - it only sets `$obj-m`, but how? By the time the 'second' read, the script should invoke Makefile in source directory (as called with `-C` options) and therefor could not set `obj-m` variable from within my current directory (the one before, it changed to source directory via `-C`). Or does the second invoking by `$(MAKE)` inherit variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the option passed to the sub-make: `M=$(PWD)`

This means the sub-make knows the working directory where your makefile exists (in its `$(M)` variable) and can then do something like `include $(M)/Makefile` to have your `obj-m` variable set.

Comment: Thats it? Without the `$(M)` variable could not resolve the makefile in source dir the `obj-m` in my dir?

Comment: I"m not an expert in Linux kernel makefiles, but as far as I know, that's it.